# Symfony 1.3 with Propel 1.5: Memory issues

Tags: symfony1, memory-management, propel

Exploring every avenue with an issue I'm currently experiencing.

I have a site that uses Symfony 1.3 with Propel, using the 1.5 plugin.
I find that my application is chewing through memory at an alarming rate.
Each instance is using 100-250 megs of memory.

I was getting "Allowed memory size" reached errors until I upped the allocated
memory size in php.ini to 256M.  That's considerably more than I'd expect to need for this application.

My old version of the same site that used Symfony 1.0 and Propel 1.3
typically used a quarter to one half as much memory for each instance.

Any suggestions on where there might be a setting in error,
perhaps a checklist for memory optimization?

Comment: No update to this issue for me yet.   I updated to the latest version of the propel 1.5 plugin, but that made no change.

Comment: This is a pretty broad question and hard to respond to with no detailed information.
Try to isolate the area in your app that is causing the memory consumption.

In my experience with Propel & Doctrine, memory consumption becomes an issue when you do large numbers of inserts or updates. For such instances I have opted to use PDO instead. You loose the convenience of the ORM, but you make huge gains in performance and memory use. In some cases it would simply not work with the ORM.
But before you go ripping out Propel, I would start profiling to find the code that is causing this.

Answer (score 2):

[This page](http://www.pmsipilot.org/2012/01/13/eviter-les-fuites-memoire-avec-propel/) gives some pointers.

Google seems to [translate it](http://translate.google.fr/translate?hl=fr&sl=fr&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.pmsipilot.org%2F2012%2F01%2F13%2Feviter-les-fuites-memoire-avec-propel%2F) rather correctly

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you! I am doing Batch Inserts with propel, and the memory consuption was killing me, not to mention it was **slow**!
With the tips mentioned in the links it works now very fast und woth low memory usage!
Again: Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You should update to Propel 1.6.3 IMO ;)